# What is the least acceleration that the block stays still on the moving ramp?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

Suppose there is a block of mass m on a ramp with angle $\alpha$ that is moving to the right with acceleration a. There is friction between the ramp and the block where $\tan(\alpha)>\mu$. I want to find the least and the most acceleration that the block stays still. I tried this:
$$N\sin(\alpha) - F_s\cos(\alpha)=ma$$
$$N = mg \cos(\alpha)$$
$$F_s = N\mu$$
So I have:
$$mg\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)-mg\cos^2(\alpha)\mu=ma \Rightarrow a = g(\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)-\cos^2(\alpha)\mu)$$
If I want the block not to move down I should have:
$$F_s=mg \sin(\alpha)$$

I don't know If I'm doing it write and I don't know how to find the "least" amount of a!

Comment: This is a really poor sketch. It is mixing together forces and accelerations and even resulting vectors along with component vectors. My guess is that  $ma$ represents som inertial tendency for the block, but this is really bad practice in regular problem-solving. Where do you have this sketch from?

Comment: @Steeven I wanted to solve this problem but with friction. But I really get confused solving that and I even asked it here and asked for help but my question has been closed! So I searched for similar questions and I find this.

Comment: @Steeven I've added the main question.

Comment: Alright, you may have been unfortunate with the sketch you found. I don't think this is of any help, rather the contrary. I'd recommend looking for excercises for problem-solving practice in regular physics book - you can always ask a question in this forum here if you just ask to the doubt or confusion rather than asking for a full answer to the problem. I will try to create an answer below.

Comment: I don't quite get why this (now edited-out) sketch is critizised so much. Granted, one could make it bigger and name the individual arrows, possibly all with their own symbol and then give the equation for those symbols as now found in the sketch. Alas... better than nothing. And with the explanations given...

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in a comment, this sketch is at least misleading and at most wrong. I would never mix arrows for forces *and* acceleration or resulting vectors *and* vector components into the same sketch. And the reason for a backwards-directed $ma$ vector, I can't tell.

***Edit:*** From a comment I now realise that the $ma$ indication comes from the solution considering the scenario from the reference frame of the moving slope. When your frame is itself accelerating, then all non-accelerating parts will appear due to their inertia to accelerate the opposite way. This is why the block seems to have a tendency to move leftwards when seen from the slope. I would not recomment using the method of looking at the scenario from an accelerating reference frame. That requires a good overview and can easily lead to confusing since pseudoforces and inertial tendencies will appear and might be counterintuitive. Instead, I'd recommend to always look at this from an inertial frame - see the description below.

---

To solve your question I'd rather simply draw the forces only. Normal force, $n$, perpendicular from the slope, weight, $w=mg$, straight downwards and friction, $f_s$, up along the slope. Since you are being asked about the stationary box, we will use static friction, $f_s$. Since you are being asked to find the limit of this static friction, we'll use the limiting formula:

$$f_{s,\text{max}}=\mu_s n.$$

With these forces, drawn on the sketch, simply use Newton's 2nd law. I would start with the law along the horizontal direction (sum up all forces along the x-axis). You might need to set up the law along the vertical direction also, in order to find some unknowns. Just keep in mind at all times what you are seeking: the acceleration $a$, which happens to be horizontal in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried that way but unfortunately, I couldn't solve it. I've seen this force in this site, too: https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/a-block-is-kept-on-a-frictionless-inclined-surface-with-angle-of-inclination-alpha/

Comment: @Mina Alright, the leftwards $ma$ indication is drawn because the solution looks at the scenario from the frame of the moving slope itself. I would recommend that you look at the whole scenario from the ground frame. That is an intetial frame and thus you don't have to worry about pseudoforces or similar and then the acceleration will only be rightwards, which is more intuitive.

Comment: @Mina If you have tried my recommended method in the answer here, but haven't managed to make it work, then you could describe the steps you've tried in the question and I have an have a look at the details. It is possibly a small issue you are running into.

Comment: I've made some changes. Please take a look at it.

Comment: weight is not gravitational force. Using standard notation also would help.

Comment: @planetmaker Excuse me? Weight is not gravitational force? Would you mind clarifying, as I certainly disagree with that statement.

Comment: @planetmaker Regarding standard notation, I'll prefer keeping the lower-case symbols that I am used to where I come from at the Technical University of Denmark. These lower-case symbols are also standard use in textbooks such as University Physics by Young and Freedman. I am not convinced that something else should be more universally accepted or an official standard. But thanks for the comment.

Comment: Weight is measured by a scale. But that is in the standard case defined by the gravitational attraction and opposed by the centrifugal force due the planet's rotation. As such we have actually $g$ as function of latitude $g = g(\theta)$. To avoid confusion with laymen terms, mixing mass and weight, it's better use 'gravitational force' than every-day words possibly ladden with wrong concepts

Comment: @planetmaker I'd argue that the term *weight* is exactly the same as *gravitational force*, but that we just, as you point out, can measure it with some error due to influencing effects like the centrifugal effect. Changing $w$ to $F_g$ and calling it gravitational force makes no sense if you keep the formula $mg$, since this error is incorporated in the value of $g$.

Comment: even if you prefer non-standard notation, using the one from the question would be a better choice :)

Comment: @planetmaker That's a fair point - but in my defence, the question has been edited and the notation added *after* I wrote my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

This problem tries to solve forces balance when ramp is moving with acceleration to the right and block experiences pseudo force $F_{ps}$ in opposite direction. In this case full equilibrium equation is :

$$ (W \sin \alpha - F_{ps} \cos \alpha) + \text {sgn}(F_{ps} \cos \alpha - W \sin \alpha) ~F_{sf} = 0$$

Where $W = mg$ is body weight, $F_{ps} = ma_{ramp}$ - pseudo force due to ramp acceleration, $F_{sf} = \mu_s mg~\cos \alpha$ - static friction force, $\text {sgn}$ - sign function, which works like $\text {sgn} (x) = \frac {x}{|x|}$, except for $0$ singularity, so function returns $-1$ or $+1$ (in specific case $x=0$ it can be agreed that it should return $0$). By using this forces equilibrium equation, one can solve for terminal ramp acceleration $a_{ramp}$ which when exceeded makes block move upwards the ramp.

Now one may ask,- why sign function is needed here ? It's because friction force direction is not fixed. Friction force opposes to a movement in general. And movement of block can be **downwards**, if gravity is stronger than pseudo-force due to ramp movement. Or **upwards**, if in reverse, pseudo-force is greater than a gravitational pull-down. Because static friction will oppose net "driving force" which direction is not known in advance,- we need ability to dynamically adjust friction force direction.

Comment: I don't understand why did you multiply $\text {sgn}(F_{ps} \cos \alpha - W \sin \alpha)$ to $F_{sf}$. If the block is likely to move downward, if I want it to be stationary then $F_{sf}+F_{ps}cos(\alpha) = Wsin(\alpha)$

Comment: But you don't know in advance, in what direction block is likely to move, upwards or downwards, it depends on block mass, ramp angle, ramp acceleration. Thus you need variability, as to what net force static friction opposes.